# Shap for XGBoost which handles categorical features without one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, shapely, shap

I have an XGBoost model object, which was trained on a data which contains categorical columns as well. One hot encoding was not done, since the XGBoost was capable of taking data without manual encoding. I would like to get the Shap values for all the variables. I am using KernelExplainer (When i used TreeExplainer, it showed an error pointing the model has categorical split!) and was getting an error which shows inability to covert categorical features to float value. Is there any method for moving forward?.

```
 f = lambda inp : xgb_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(inp, enable_categorical = True))
 explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(f, X_train_new)
```

enable_categorical = False wont work, it would through another error.

Comment: It seems implemented (but I haven't tried it out myself): https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/7053 Do you have an up-to-date version of XGBoost?